# How to output Multiple elements from an XML with the same name using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

This question is a follow on from my previous post: [How to convert xml file to csv output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043913/how-to-convert-xml-file-to-csv-output-in-python)

Again, I have a basic XML file that is being pulled from a database outside of my control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<Job1Start><Time>20200202055415725</Time></Job1Start>
<Job1End><Time>20200202055423951</Time></Job1End>
<Job2Start><Time>20200202055810390</Time></Job2Start>
<Job3Start><Time>20200202055814687</Time></Job3Start>
<Job2End><Time>20200202055819000</Time></Job2End>
<Job3End><Time>20200202055816708</Time></Job3End>
<Job1Start><Time>20200203053415725</Time></Job1Start>
<Job1End><Time>20200203056423951</Time></Job1End>
</data>
```

My current code is shown below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('StackedExample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow('Task Start Finish'.split())
        tasklist = ['Job1', 'Job2','Job3']
        for Task in tasklist:
            start = root.find(f'.//{Task}Start/Time').text
            end = root.find(f'.//{Task}End/Time').text
            writer.writerow([f'{Task}',start,end])
            print(f'{Task}',start,end)
```

This outputs the below, but only gives one output for "Job1":

```
Task    Start               Finish
Job1    20200202055415725   20200202055423951
Job2    20200202055810390   20200202055819000
Job3    20200202055814687   20200202055816708
```

I'm looking to get something like this:

```
Task    Start               Finish
Job1    20200202055415725   20200202055423951
Job1    20200203053415725   20200203056423951
Job2    20200202055810390   20200202055819000
Job3    20200202055814687   20200202055816708
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find will only give you the first appearance of the tag
you can use findall, for start time, and findall for end time, then make a zip() from both of them

```
import itertools
for Task in tasklist:
    start = root.findall(f'.//{Task}Start/Time')
    start_txt = []
    for s in start:
        start_txt.append(s.text) 
    end = root.findall(f'.//{Task}End/Time')
    end_txt = []
    for e in end_txt:
        end_txt.append(e.text)
    row_list = list(zip(start_txt,end_txt))
    for row in row_list
        writer.writerow([f'{Task}',row[0],row[1]])
```

not very elegent but works

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r"D:\t.xml"
file = open(path)
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
m1 = {"Task": "Job1"}
m2 = {"Task": "Job2"}
m3 = {"Task": "Job3"}
out = []
for t in root:
    time = t.find(".//Time")
    txt = time.text
    if "1Start" in t.tag:
        m1["Start"] = txt
    if "1End" in t.tag:
        m1["End"] = txt
        out.append(m1)
    if "2Start" in t.tag:
        m2["Start"] = txt
    if "2End" in t.tag:
        m2["End"] = txt
        out.append(m2)
    if "3Start" in t.tag:
        m3["Start"] = txt
    if "3End" in t.tag:
        m3["End"] = txt
        out.append(m3)
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df.to_excel("D:\out.xlsx")
```

Comment: With this I'm getting:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: When I remove the ".text" I get:



['Job1', <Element 'Time' at 0x033D0DC0>, <Element 'Time' at 0x033D0E10>]
['Job2', <Element 'Time' at 0x033D0E88>, <Element 'Time' at 0x033D0F50>]
['Job3', <Element 'Time' at 0x033D0F00>, <Element 'Time' at 0x033D0FA0>]

Comment: my bad, try it now

Comment: Now its:
Job3 [<Element 'Time' at 0x05BD90C0>] [<Element 'Time' at 0x05BD91E0>]